# spatialite compile error under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, spatialite

I'm trying to build the following project for Android:

http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/

but it has error after   excute  "ndk-build -j10 " command.

the detail error inforamtion is :

```
    In file included from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/capi/geos_ts_c.cpp:20:0:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Envelope.h:26,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/index/strtree/STRtree.h:26,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/capi/geos_c.cpp:20:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
Compile++ thumb  : geos <= CGAlgorithms.cpp
In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/Angle.cpp:24:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/algorithm/LineIntersector.h:27,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CGAlgorithms.cpp:23:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
Compile++ thumb  : geos <= CentroidArea.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : geos <= CentroidLine.cpp
In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/algorithm/CentroidArea.h:26,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidArea.cpp:21:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
Compile++ thumb  : geos <= CentroidPoint.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : geos <= ConvexHull.cpp
In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/algorithm/CentroidLine.h:22,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidLine.cpp:19:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/algorithm/CentroidPoint.h:21,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidPoint.cpp:16:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"

In file included from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:20:0,
                 from geos-3.3.6/include/geos/algorithm/ConvexHull.h:24,
                 from /home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/jni/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/ConvexHull.cpp:21:
geos-3.3.6/include/geos/platform.h:110:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/Angle.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CGAlgorithms.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidArea.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidLine.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/CentroidPoint.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/capi/geos_c.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/src/algorithm/ConvexHull.o] Error 1
make: *** [/home/android/spatialite-android/spatialite-android-library/obj/local/armeabi/objs/geos/geos-3.3.6/capi/geos_ts_c.o] Error 1
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Have you found the solution?